# Crash in Drive Realtime API XHR Error Handler

Tags: javascript, google-drive-realtime-api

We've been seeing an significant increase in the number of script errors reported in our app that uses the Realtime API. Specifically this started happening around 1/27/16 at ~6/7PM PST. Poking around a bit I believe I was able to track this back to the XHR error callback installed by the Realtime API.

```
    function EA(a) {
        a.onerror = function() {
            self.xc()
        }
    }
```

In this handler `self` will always refer to `window.self` which seems like very much the wrong thing as there is never an `xc` function on the window object. While this doesn't appear to be causing any significantly bad behavior (although it may be contributing to further issues with re-connection), it would be great to have these errors handled.

Is this something other people are seeing as well or a known issue? Is anyone using a workaround?

Comment: Hey, this is being investigated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved and you should notice your errors diminish tomorrow when it is released.

This error does not cause any issues with re-connection. The onerror handler is invoked when there are network issues, which are (generally) automatically retried regardless of whether this particular execution path chokes at this point.

Comment: Thanks Seth, appreciate the quick resolution! We have generally only seen reconnection errors on Safari on machines that go on/off network and thought this might be related.